# Persistent state in typescript module

Tags: typescript, state

I would like to do something like this:

```js
let serialId = 0;

export function getId() {
    serialId = serialId + 1;
    return serialId;
}
```

And every time I call it from various places id would increment. Now it seems that `serialId` value is independent for every `import`.

Do I need some magical declaration or maybe even some tool to have persistent "global" state. I don't want serialId to be visible outside of module if possible.

Comment: It just works but such broadly scoped state is best avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer more functional way, you can export factory:

```
export const stateFactory = (() => {
  let id = 0;
  return ({
    getId() {
        return ++id;
    }
  })
})()

const b = stateFactory.getId(); // 1
const c = stateFactory.getId(); // 2
```

Comment: I liked this approach the most.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with methods in a class:

```js
export default class {
  serialId: number;
  constructor () {
    this.serialId = 0;
  }

  public getId(): number {
    this.serialId += 1;
    return this.serialId
  }

}
```